# In performance and efficiency , Naked variable defining Or If statement variable defining is better?

Tags: php

I was wondering about the performance of the following

If i want to assign variable i have two ways to do that

## 1: Naked Assigning

```
$variable = 'Value';
```

---

## 2: if statement Assigning.

```
if($x == true){
    $variable = 'Value';
}
```

What i know that in the first case, I just keep the variable defined in all time, But in the 2nd case, I only define it if the condition is `true`.

Which one is the best in performance and efficiency? And what do you or why would you suggest to use?

In both cases there would be another statement that would be used like this

```
if($x == true){
    echo $variable;
}
```

that would use the variable, But Is it better to wrap the variable in `If statement` too? Since in first case, The variable won't be used unless `x == true` but in second case the variable would be **defined and used** if `x == true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't worry about it.**

Use whichever form makes your code more readable and understandable.

What if the first one takes 1 microsecond and the second takes 10 microseconds.  One runs in 1/10th the time, but neither is discernible.  Even if you're executing that 1,000 times, now you're only improving the runtime by 1/1000th of a second.

You are figuring out microseconds of difference that are not going to affect the run-time of your application.  The run-time of assigning variables is insignificant to the time spent fetching things from a database and sending it across the wire.

If you really think that you are having performance problems with your app, use a tool like [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) to profile your code and find out where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I do realize that the different is too small, But i just want to know if it is faster and efficient to keep the variable defined Or do i use an If statement to define it, Like if the if statement would reduce the size a little since it is not defined unless the `x == true`, Or the checking process is actually increasing the time.

Comment: Then use a tool like XDebug to measure two different pieces of code.